# Unable to override Mui Accordion using Styled Utility

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

I want to override Accordion CSS using Mui styled utility but I am unable to get apply Accordion css onto it. There's an underlying class which I can't point to in my code. This is the mui class:

```
<div class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation MuiPaper-rounded MuiPaper-elevation1 MuiAccordion-root MuiAccordion-rounded MuiAccordion-gutters css-1elwnq4-MuiPaper-root-MuiAccordion-root" style="user-select: auto;">
```

This is my code for Accordion

```js
const CustomizedAccordion = styled(Accordion)<AccordionProps>(({ theme }) => ({
    root: {
        "& .MuiPaper-root": {
            color: 'darkslategray',
            backgroundColor: '#E4FAF4',
            borderRadius: '0.6rem',
            boxShadow: 'none'
        }
    
    },
    paddingBottom: '1.6rem',
    boxShadow: 'none',

}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const CustomizedAccordion = styled(Accordion)(() => ({
  '& .MuiPaper-root': {
    color: 'darkslategray',
    backgroundColor: '#E4FAF4',
    borderRadius: '0.6rem',
    boxShadow: 'none'
  },
  paddingBottom: '1.6rem',
  boxShadow: 'none'
}));
```

Comment: Not sure why but I cant seem to get this working, nothing happens..

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem but when I read MUI docs in detail. Basically they set square corners by default 'true'.
To change square corners to rounded, we need to change this default value of sqaure prop as false.
They use sx prop to set border radius.

```
<Accordion square='false' sx={{borderRadius: '30px', background: 'tan'}}>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhOpf.png)

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 2):

```
<Accordion square={true} sx={{borderRadius: '30px'}}>
```

`square` should be boolean - if you set it to true you can add `borderRadius` in `sx`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution is in the props

```
<Accordion disableGutters />
```

If you set it to true, the margin disappears. [Link to Accordion API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/accordion/#props)

Answer (score -3):

I want to modify expanded style from its style which has code as
`.css-kj1tus-MuiPaper-root-MuiAccordion-root.Mui-expanded { margin: 16px 0; }`
to `margin:0px 0px 0px 4px`;

But, unable to make it working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not a good idea to post your query as an answer to a question.